# SQLite+SQLAlchemy+Python3: Could not decode to UTF-8 column

Tags: python, sqlite, python-3.x, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a SQLAlchemy model, in a Flask app, defined like this:

```
class Food(Model):
    __tablename__ = 'food'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    short_desc = db.Column(db.String(80))
    sci_name = db.Column(db.String(250))
```

I'm trying to perform a simple query using a pre-filled SQLite database, but when I call `Food.query.all()` I receive the error:

```
(sqlite3.OperationalError) Could not decode to UTF-8 column 'food_sci_name' with text 'Actinidia chinensis �Zesy002� (Gold3)'
```

I tried changing the engine `text_factory` to `str`, to `bytes` but none of these changes have made any difference.

Answer (score 0):

column `sci_name` contains some characters which `text_factory` can not convert. the default `text_factory` is `str`, you can change it:

```
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///some.db')
engine.connect().connection.text_factory = lambda x: x.decode('utf-8', errors='ignore')
```